# Using AngularJS $http with WordPress doesn't respond as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I've done a `wp_localize_script` for my ajax in wordpress:

```
wp_localize_script('cb_admin_js', 'cbAjax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
```

In angular I've doing an `$http.get()` to perform a test:

```
$http.get('http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',{action:'get_saved_cover'}).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

My function should just return a set of cars:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_saved_cover', 'get_saved_cover' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_saved_cover', 'get_saved_cover' );

function get_saved_cover(){
    $cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
    return json_encode($cars);
    wp_die();
}
```

I'm only getting back `data: 0`, `status: 200`, and a few other standard responses in an array. I'm not sure I'm missing a piece that Angular wants, or what.

Answer (score 0):

Change the angular http argument to params instead of data

```
 $http({
    url: 'http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    method: "GET",
    params: {action: "get_saved_cover"}
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response.data);
});
```